# when should I use okhttp-coroutines-jvm?

Tags: retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

Using `Retrofit2` + `okhttp3`, but I've noticed the [bom](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp-bom) contains `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines`. And saw this dependency `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines-jvm` in some projects. I'm wondering in which scenario I should this? Does Retrofit support kotlin corotine internally?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use this library with Retrofit, you don’t need it.

Comment: thanks, could you share a little bit more the detail?

Answer (score 0):

For at least most libraries where the name ends in `-jvm`, these are libraries that are specifically tailored to work with the (J)ava (V)irtual (M)achine. If you look at the `Kotlin` standard libraries you will find libraries like `kotlin-stdlib-js`, `kotlin-stdlib`, `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`, `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, `kotlin-stdlib-wasm` and so on, although not really one specific for the JVM. Kotlin runs originally in the JVM, so that accounts to why. The same thing happens with `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines-jvm`. This is sometimes needed or it is just better optimized in some plugin/library version for whatever reason. In the case of `Retrofit2`, at least for the version I checked, `2.1.0`, I see that it already comes with `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0`. But this isn't the coroutines library. If I add `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines:5.0.0-alpha.12`, then I see that namely the `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3` is added along with the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines-jvm:5.0.0-alpha.12`. So if you add the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines:5.0.0-alpha.12` you won't need to further add the `jvm` related library. However you may also need to only add the `jvm` library. This is why they are delivered separately. Also, instead of version `3.3.0` we then get `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.12`.

So, long story short, you don't need the `-jvm` library in this case because you already have it using the `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-coroutines:5.0.0-alpha.12` and that `-jvm` library is specifically made to run in the JVM.